# RTMPT Fallback on port 80 with MediaElementJS

Tags: flash, nginx, rtmp, mediaelement.js

In our current business case we have clients opening a MediaElementJS browsing the player page via a firewall protected network.

When the TCP Port 1935 is blocked by firewalls we want the Player to understand that the port is blocked and try the connection for the streaming towards the server by switching to the RMTPT protocol (protocol rollover) and so using HTTP Port 80.

We already configured our NGINX to redirect traffic internally from Port 80 to 5080 (our RED5 Server listening for HTTP/RTMPT).

We tried doing tests simulating the inbound/outbound connection block of port 1935 on the client.

Looks like the MediaElementJS simply does nothing when the Play button is pressed.

Is this protocol rollover / fallback on port 80 with RTMPT feature available on MediaElementJS ?

Does somebody had the same problem and can explain possibile solutions to it ?

We have:

nginx 0.7.43
Red5 1.0.5
MediaElementJS 2.1.2.0 (not sure about this version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was not a problem of MediaElementJS.

The RTMP protocol is transparent to the player.

What was required it was a correct configuration of the nginx to forward certain types of HTTP Requests to the RMTPT TCP internal port of the Red5 server.

After setting up nginx correctly we tested the port 80 fallback successfully.